# How to dispatch an array from a Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is my reducer code,

```
export default function homeReducer(state = {}, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case types.GET_USER_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.user);

    case types.GET_MEDIA_FOR_USER_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.medias);

    default:
      return state;


  }
}
```

Now user is an object by medias is an array of object.

Now when I pass medias to my component,

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
  return {
    user: state.home,
    medias: state.home
  };
}
```

I get a validation error, against this code,

```
HomePage.propTypes = {

  user : PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  medias: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `medias` of type `object` supplied to `HomePage`, expected `array`. Check the render method of `Connect(HomePage)`.
```

I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Well, it says it in the error: `medias` is expected to be an array. Change the prop type to object and you should be good.

Comment: What I'm passing is an array and not an object and I need to map over the array in the HomePage component which I'm not able to do.

Comment: What I can see from your reducer is that you're passing an object, not an array (via `Object.assign`). So make sure it's actually an array then.

Comment: Your mapping function is doing `state.home` for both `user` and `medias`

Comment: @FabianSchultz how do I pass an array in the reducer.

Comment: I can't really tell without knowing what your state actually looks like. Right now you're combining `state` and `medias` with `Object.assign`, which returns an object. You need to create an array with `[]` or use `.join()` to return an array.

Comment: The reducer has a state, one of which is a property that is an array. The state is still an object. Medias is a property in the object which is an array. So how do I return a new state updating only the array prop of the reducer.

Comment: When you're passing: `medias: state.medias` instead of `medias: state.home`?

Comment: Home is the name of the reducer, its an alias for homeReducer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
Object.assign({}, array)
```

To

```
 [...array]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
export default function homeReducer(state = { user: {}, media: [] }, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case types.GET_USER_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { user: action.user });

    case types.GET_MEDIA_FOR_USER_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { media: action.medias });

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Then...

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
  return {
    user: state.home.user,
    medias: state.home.media
  };
}
```

Just make sure your `action.medias` is indeed an array.